# How HTML document parses in MVC using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, optimization

As per Steve Souders book on Even Faster Websites

*Simplified Quote*

> server parses PHP page and all output is written to STDOUT, so flush() on right place causes anything queued up to be sent immediately as oppose to larger chunks

If I am using IIS, how does HTML document parse flows like in PHP i.e. ob_start() opens a new output buffer, then ob_flush() flushes the contents of output buffer to STDOUT and then flush() flushes out STDOUT?

Any link or hints would be appreciated.

*Note: I know the book is old and even the example links doesn't work as expected, but still want to go over basics*

Comment: IIS doesn't parse HTML, it's your browser that does that. What exactly do you mean? Are you curious about why you would use output buffering?

Comment: @CodeCaster I wonder if browser is solely responsible for parsing how would razor syntax or php syntax (inline) output value or are they independent of server?

Comment: You're mixing up a lot of concepts there. PHP is an interpreted language, interpreted by a program running on and invoked by your web server. Razor is parsed by the Razor view engine of ASP.NET MVC, which translates it to C# code and then compiles and runs it, which again, happens on the server. So is your actual question _"How do Razor views output HTML"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster kind of yes, even on server side syntax on webforms or prior to razor,  I guess it has something to do with server? or is it done solely on client?